# Use power series to solve the differential equation

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the differential equation

\begin{align}
t\frac{dy}{dt} - t^2y + 5 &= 0 \\
y(0) &= 0
\end{align}

I want to solve this using power series, so consider

$$y(t)=a_{0}+a_{1}t+a_{2}t^2+\cdots=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}t^{n}$$
and
$$\frac{dy}{dt}=a_{1}+2a_{2}t+3a_{3}t^2+\cdots=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}na_{n}t^{n-1}$$

Note that

\begin{align*}
    0&=t\frac{dy}{dt}-t^2y+5 \\
    &=t\left(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}na_{n}t^{n-1} \right)-t^2\left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}t^{n} \right)+5 \hspace{0.4cm} (\ast)
\end{align*}

The idea here would be to arrive at an expression of the form $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} z k^n=0$ and then $k=0$ where can I establish a recurrence relation knowing that $a_{0}=y(0)=1$ but my problem occurs when simplifying $(\ast)$, any suggestions on how to solve this? I appreciate it!

Answer (score 3):

You would want to distribute the $t$ terms into your summations and change the bounds on your summations so that they start at the same $n$ value, for example

$\displaystyle{t\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}na_nt^{n-1} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}na_nt^{n} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(n+1)a_{n+1}t^{n+1}}$.

Now you can distribute $t^2$ into the second term and combine the $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}$ terms.

However if we follow through with this we'll see that we have something in the form ($\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} + 5$) where the lowest $t^n$ exponent is $t^1$, therefore this cannot be solved through this method. It's interesting to examine the initial differential equation at $t=0$, by doing so we see that $0(y')+0(y)+5=0,$ so $5=0$, we can conclude that the function is not well defined at $t=0$ and cannot be a power series solution of this form.

Comment: Good note, given what you mentioned, is there any way to correct that at $t=0$ it is not well defined? perhaps considering another center for the power series? thank you!

Comment: I'm not sure, if the goal is to just solve the differential equation I would go through the route of using an integration factor as explained in this wikipedia link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrating_factor going through this method instead leads more directly to the answer

Comment: I thought you started by finding the homogenous solution and then used that to find the non-homogenous solution