# Solve differential equation using power series

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Relating the question I asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4786909/use-power-series-to-solve-the-differential-equation/4786925#4786925) i wondered how to solve the following differential equation using power series

\begin{align}
t\frac{dy}{dt} - t^2y &= 0 \\
y(0) &= 1
\end{align}

Consider

$$y(t)=a_{0}+a_{1}t+a_{2}t^2+\cdots=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}t^{n}$$
From where
$$\frac{dy}{dt}=a_{1}+2a_{2}t+3a_{3}t^2+\cdots=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}na_{n}t^{n-1}$$

Then

\begin{align*}
    0&=t\frac{dy}{dt}-t^2y \\
    &=t\left(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}na_{n}t^{n-1} \right)-t^2\left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}t^{n} \right) \\
    &=\left(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}na_{n}t^{n} \right)-\left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}t^{n+2} \right) \\
    &=\left(\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(k+1)a_{k+1}t^{k+1}\right)-\left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{k}t^{k+2} \right)\\
    &=\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} ((k+1)a_{k+1}t-a_{k}t^{2})t^k
\end{align*}

And

$$(k+1)a_{k+1}t-a_{k}t^{2}=0 \hspace{0.3cm} \forall k\in \mathbb{N}$$

Now, it seems that from this it is necessary to apply some type of recurrence relation in order to reach the result, but I do not see it clear, any suggestions? I appreciate it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try going from here
$$
t \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{n a_n t^{n-1}} - t^2 \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{a_nt^n} = 0 \\
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{n a_n t^{n}} - \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{a_nt^{n+2}} = 0
$$
the reason your method doesn't quite work is because what you want to do is compare coefficients, since
$$
0 = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{0\cdot x^n}
$$
so in this case to try and get the LHS of the equation into a form where we can compare coeffs we could remove the first term from the summation and re-index from there
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{n a_n t^{n}} - \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{a_nt^{n+2}} = 0
\\
a_1 t + \sum_{n=2}^{\infty}{n a_n t^{n}} - \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{a_nt^{n+2}} = 0
\\
a_n t + \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{(n+2) a_{n+2} t^{n+2}} - \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{a_nt^{n+2}} = 0
$$
and from here you can combine them and set it equal to 0
$$
a_1 t + \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{({(n+2) a_{n+2} - a_n })t^{n+2}}= 0
$$
so from this you would conclude that
$$ 
a_1 = 0
$$
and that
$$
(n+2) a_{n+2} - a_n = 0
$$
and you should use this second equation to find your recurrence relationship for the coeffs

Comment: Your help has been useful, from it I deduced that all the odd terms are $0$ but I have a doubt with the even terms, because i think that $a_{k+2}=\frac{a_{k}}{k+2}$ and $a_{2}=\frac{1}{2}$, $a_{4}=\frac{a_{2}}{4}=\frac{\frac{1}{2}}{4}=2$, $a_{6}=\frac{a_{4}}{6}=\frac{2}{6}$, etc. but is there a way to generalize the even therm?

Comment: Another thing is why $a_{1}=0$ from $$a_1 t + \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{({(k+2) a_{k+2} - a_k })t^{k+2}}= 0$$?

Comment: $a_1=0$ follows from the RHS being $0+0t+0t^2...$ you get that $a_1=0$ by comparing coefficents.

you are almost right about the recurrence relationship but it would be more helpful to try it like this

let $a_0 = c$  then from the relation $a_{n+2} = \frac{a_n}{n+2}$ we can see that it follows $a_{2} = \frac{a_0}{2}$,$a_{4} = \frac{c}{2\cdot4}$, $a_{6} = \frac{c}{2\cdot4\cdot6}$ and so in general you notice that $a_{2n} = \frac{c}{2\cdot4...\cdot(2n+2)}$ and if you factor a 2 out of all the fractions the pattern becomes $a_{2n} = \frac{c}{2^n(1\cdot2...\cdot(n+1))}$ which is

Comment: $a_{2n} = \frac{c}{2^n n!)}$ which you can then notice is the same as the coefficients of $e^x$ if $x=\frac{t^2}{2}$ hence the solutions to your differential equation would be $y = c e^{t^2}$. also would be worth looking into integrating factors since that would help solve this equation much quicker

Comment: I appreciate it! it has been very useful